# Visual Studio 2012 C# Form application using log(base 10) function

Tags: c#, forms

I'm writing a program in Visual Studio 2012 C# Form application. I want to use log(base 10) in it for calculation after a button is clicked. I saw a code and I wrote that in my program but it is giving me an error. Where am I getting wrong?

```
    public static decimal Log10(
        decimal value 
    )
```

Comment: What you have is a method declaration with no method implementation. Also, if you got an error message, why don't you put it in you question?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually implement the function and not only declare it:

```
public static decimal Log10(decimal value)
{
    return Math.Log10((double)value);
}
```

Well, as you can see there's already such function built into the .NET framework: [`Math.Log10`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.log10.aspx). So you probably don't need to reinvent the wheel, but simply use it.